iOS Safari WebDriver executeScript fails to serialize objects with elements
In iOS Safari, executeScript fails to serialize objects containing WebElements, while the same code works in Firefox, chrome and even IE.
I've tried running:
const elements = await driver.$$('.my-class-name');
await driver.execute(function(args) {
  return args.elements[0].tagName;
}, { elements });

On Chrome, it returns "DIV", but on Safari, it returns null.
When I tried:
const elements = await driver.$$('.my-class-name');
await driver.execute(function(args) {
  return args[0].tagName;
}, elements);

it worked fine on both.
when debugging on Safari, each element was a large object with sessionId and more webdriver-related info.
Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is it a bug in Safari or WebDriver? What’s the expected behavior?
